# Optimising the Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo aggregation pipeline while runs something like following

```
            {
                $match: {
                    "cohortId": payload.cohortId, "template": req.query.template
                },
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "messages", localField: "messageId", foreignField: "metaData.messageId", as: "message"
                }
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "webhook", localField: "messageId", foreignField: "messageId", as: "webhook"
                }
            }, {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$webhook"
                }
            }, {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$message"
                }
            },

            {
                $project: {
                    "_id": 0,
                    "messageId": 1,
                    "cohortId": 1,
                    "template": 1,
                    "origin": 1,
                    "WBA_AccountId": 1,
                    "WBA_PhoneId": 1,
                    "clientPhone": "$phone",
                    "messageDirection": "$message.metaData.direction",
                    "messageTime": "$message.metaData.time",
                    "messageSent": "$webhook.status.sentFlag",
                    "messageDelivered": "$webhook.status.deliveredFlag",
                    "messageRead": "$webhook.status.readFlag",
                    "messageFailed": "$webhook.status.failedFlag",
                    "messageFailedReason": "$webhook.status.failedReason",
                    "messageSentTime": "$webhook.status.sentTimestamp",
                    "messageDeliveredTime": "$webhook.status.deliveredTimestamp",
                    "messageReadTime": "$webhook.status.readTimestamp",
                    "messageFailedTime": "$webhook.status.failedTimestamp"
                }
            },
```

Where the Data in Web hook is as

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6374d59618bff45fa34f08f5"
  },
  "messageId": "<Message ID as String>",
  "conversationExpiry": 1668687660,
  "conversationId": "<Conversation ID as String>",
  "billableFlag": "true",
  "WBA_PhoneId": 1234567890, //masked
  "WBA_AccountId": 1234567890, //masked
  "WBA_DisplayPhone": 1234567890, //masked
  "phone": 1234567890, //masked
  "status": {
    "sentFlag": true,
    "sentTimestamp": 1668601237,
    "deliveredFlag": true,
    "readFlag": true,
    "failedFlag": false,
    "deliveredTimestamp": 1668601238,
    "readTimestamp": 1668601250,
    "failedTimestamp": 0,
    "errorMessage": "",
    "errorCode": ""
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1668601238086"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1668601250918"
    }
  }
}
```

and Audience Data looks like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "635a840b97405992d3cb794d"
  },
  "WBA_AccountId": 1234567890, //masked
  "WBA_PhoneId": 1234567890, //masked
  "messageId": "<Message ID as String>",
  "phone": 1234567890, //masked
  "cohortId": "<String Value, I refer this in Aggregation Pipeline to trigger it>",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666876427333"
    }
  },
  "end": "2022-10-27",
  "origin": "Clevertap_API_Campaigns",
  "start": "2022-10-27",
  "template": "<String Value, I refer this in Aggregation Pipeline to trigger it>",
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666876427333"
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem**

When I hit the Controller to trigger the pipeline, with Cohort and Template, it takes 3 minutes to iterate over 6000ish documents and network call times out.

What can be done to optimise the pipeline?

Am using M10 Atlas Cluster

Edit:
Adding Screenshot of Realtime Metrics
[Cluster Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K6hZ.png)

Comment: To better understand what is happening here, please gather and provide the explain plan with execution stats for the aggregation (`.explain("executionStats")`). Without that we can only really guess at what is happening here. Also, what is your performance target here? It sounds like 3 minutes is too slow, but how fast are you trying to get it to be? Finally, what is that `6,000` number referring to, the number of documents in the source collection that match the `cohortId` and `template` values in the `$match` stage?

Comment: I think on the aggregation pipeline there is not much you can do. But you may review your data design. Why do you store the data in three different collections? Typically in MongoDB the number of collections is much less than the number of tables in according RDBMS application.

Comment: Hello @user20042973
Here is the output of Explain --> https://katb.in/zadequmubec

6000 is typically the no of docs returned by the pipeline as result. Currently the webhook collection has 19,265 and audiences has 19,205 documents in it

Comment: Use indexs on your foreign fields. Its doing a full COLLSCAN of that collection, adding an index to  `metaData.messageId` and `messageId` will speed it up dramatically.

Comment: @AdamExchange I had a index like this in the system https://imgur.com/a/nQ0gJC4

Comment: Even tried creating a `text` index on `metaData.messageId` but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 opportunities to use indexes in this aggregation pipeline, and currently the database is unable to do so at all.

The first opportunity is with the initial `$match` on the `audiances` collection. There are two fields being filtered on, `cohortId` and `template`. Both have equality predicates, so the index keys could be in either order:

```
db.getSiblingDB('Production').audiances.createIndex({ cohortId:1, template:1 })
```

Similarly, the database can try to use indexes for both of the `$lookup` operations. Currently it is doing about 10,000 full scans of each collection:

```
            {
                "$lookup": 
                ...
                "totalDocsExamined": 97236382,
                "collectionScans": 9908,
                "indexesUsed": [],
            },
            {
                "$lookup": 
                ...
                "totalDocsExamined": 95408871,
                "collectionScans": 9906,
                "indexesUsed": [],
            },
```

You [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74460935/optimising-the-aggregation-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment131448357_74460935) that you "*had a index like this in the system*" [and that you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74460935/optimising-the-aggregation-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment131448509_74460935) "*tried creating a `text` index on `metaData.messageId`*". The latter index is not appropriate as you are not performing [a $text search](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/text-search/) so it cannot be used. And the first index shown in your screenshot is `{ phone: 1, metadata.messageid: 1 }`. This index cannot be used either since the *first* key (`phone`) is not part of your query (`$lookup`).

As `$lookup` will do a direct comparison, the following two indexes will (drastically) improve the performance and efficiency of the operation:

```
db.getSiblingDB('Production').messages.createIndex({ "metaData.messageId": 1 })
db.getSiblingDB('Production').webhook.createIndex ({ "messageId": 1 })
```

Comment: Thanks @user20042973 for the solution, its now running the pipeline in 1276ms!!